# Adding a total to legend in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, legend

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Report Builder 2.0 and I'm wondering how to add a total to the legend. I have used custom code for other graphs but I would like to know if there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the series properties, Legend tab, you can specify "Custom legend text". You can construct it with an expression in SSRS or in the SQL query and use the field value.

Comment: What would that expression be? To have the last line in the legend be the total.